# rails restful filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index action and I would like the user to be able to filter the results on the index page by clicking on "filter links" on the same page.

There is a nice [railcasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form) video that allows you to filter results by typing into a search box.

I would like to filter results based on links the user clicks. How can I do this? Is there a way I can pass params to the controller using link_to?

for example, on an index page listing books, I would like to display the following link

```
<%= link_to "Fiction", books_path %>
```

and clicking the link would then only display books in the fiction category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597) section "link_to can also produce links with anchors or query strings:"

So you example would look like (assuming a "category" filter):

```
<%= link_to "Fiction", books_path(:category => "fiction") %>
```

Comment: I tried this, but I cant seem to access params[:category] in the controller.
params[:category].inspect returns nil

Comment: oops... updated the code example.  The category is passed in to books_path. You should see the generated link containing "category=fiction" in the form "/books?category=fiction".

Comment: That worked, The correct syntax is this
<%= link_to "Fiction", books_path(:category => "fiction) %>
Now params[:category] will be available in the controller.

Thanks!